# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Vue.util.hyphenate is not a function

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to setup vuejs with onsen ui and I get this error:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Vue.util.hyphenate is not a function

Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onsen/2.1.0/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onsen/2.1.0/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onsen/2.1.0/js/onsenui.js">        </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-onsenui@2.0.0-alpha.0"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template:
      '<v-ons-page>\
         <v-ons-toolbar>\
           <div class="center"> Title </div>\
         </v-ons-toolbar>\
         <p style="text-align: center">\
           <v-ons-button @click="$notification.alert(\'Hello World!\')">Click</v-ons-button>\
         </p>\
       </v-ons-page>'
  });
</script>
</html>
```

I can't find this as an known issue. I also tried with older version od vue like 2.0.0.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Sir,I meet the same error with you, and I try to find the error and solve it.
First of all, download the "https://unpkg.com/vue-onsenui@2.0.0-alpha.0", and change you script dom's src to your local's.
Then you can open the "vue-onsenui@2.0.0-alpha.0" and find these code:

```js
var register = function register(Vue, type, items) {
   (0, _keys2.default)(items).forEach(function (key) {
     var value = items[key];
     key = Vue.util.hyphenate(key);
     Vue[type](key, value);
   });
 };
```

So you can see the "Vue.util.hyphenate" ,but now vue don't have this function. Please use the same function from this file.

ex:

```js
var register = function register(Vue, type, items) {
   (0, _keys2.default)(items).forEach(function (key) {
     var value = items[key];
     var hyphenate = function hyphenate(string) {
     return string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
  };
     key = hyphenate(key);
     Vue[type](key, value);
   });
 };
```

My English is so bad, and sorry to use your time.

Answer (score 2):

In the last version Vue.js many exposed methods and properties on Vue.util have been removed.

So, you need download javascript file (https://unpkg.com/vue-onsenui@2.0.0-alpha.0) and replace code in 67 line:

```js
key = Vue.util.hyphenate(key);
```

to this code:

```js
key = key.replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
```